# Incorrect syntax near table name- update query, tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
set @SQLQuery = 'update top (200) ' +@tablename+ 
  ' set Flag1 = ''new'' where [Flag1] = '+@flag1+'';
```

Comment: Got solution: exec('update top(200)'+@tablename+' set Flag1 = '''+@flag1+''' where Flag1 = ''new''');

Comment: As a good practice do not construct your query from parameters, since it will induce [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, @yildizm85. I'll keep in mind for my future implementations as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

set @SQLQuery = 'update ' +@tablename+ 
  ' set Flag1 = ''new'' where [Flag1] = '+@flag1+' AND Flag1 IN (SELET TOP 200 Flag1 FROM ' +@tablename+ 'WHERE [Flag1] = '+@flag1+')';

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions, here is my solution.                     exec('update top(200)'+@tablename+' set Flag1 = '''+@flag1+''' where Flag1 = ''new''');